# Apple Metal blitCommandEncoder in multi-thread situation

Tags: metal

I have a loop that send off jobs to GPU in the managed memory model. code is:

```
var commandBufferArray : [MTLCommandBuffer] = []
var blitCommandArray : [MTLBlitCommandEncoder] = []

for i_cycle in 0..<n
{
    commandBufferArray.append(mc.metalCommandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()) 
    let outputDeviate = [float4](repeating: float4(0.0),count: 1024)           
    outputDeviateBufferArray.append(mc.createFloat4MetalBufferManaged(outputDeviate))

    populateBuffersMetalJob(.....)

    blitCommandArray.append(commandBufferArray[i_cycle].makeBlitCommandEncoder())   
    blitCommandArray[i_cycle].synchronize(resource: outputDeviateBufferArray[i_cycle])
    blitCommandArray[i_cycle].endEncoding()

    commandBufferArray[i_cycle].addCompletedHandler({ _ in      
     // do stuff with result
    })  

    commandBufferArray[i_cycle].commit()    
}            

for i_cycle in 0..<numCycles
{
    commandBufferArray[i_cycle].waitUntilCompleted()
}
```

I am using the AMD process on a 2015 MBP. If n = 1, this works fine. Once n > 1, it seems to hang on the synchronization call and never completes.

Any thoughts on what is going wrong here?

Comment: I just noticed that the two `for` loops use different ranges (`n` vs. `numCycles`). Is that intentional?

Comment: typo as I formatted it. Not the issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

What is in the `// do stuff with result` code? I suspect you're doing something in there that's deadlocking. Perhaps it's trying to run something on the main thread where the code you've shown is blocked. Or it's trying to access a resource that you have locked. That prevents the completed handler(s) from finished, which prevents the command buffer from moving on and letting the next command buffer run or complete.

If you take a sample of the process, it can provides hints about where it's stuck and what it's waiting for. You can do that using the `sample` command-line tool or Activity Monitor > View > Sample Process.

Also, why are you using multiple command buffers? And why multiple blit command encoders? You do realize you could do all of this using a single command buffer and a single blit command encoder, right?

Comment: Ken, thank you very much for this. I have commented out the section in the completion handler // do stuff... and it still hangs (requires the whole MBP to be rebooted).

Comment: I use multiple command buffers in other to execute different data sets simultaneously. I am aware in this case that it could all be done sequentially (and presumably reuse the command buffer once it was completed) as it is FIFO on the command queue but am trying to do this in a more general case where different CPU threads are launching jobs onto the GPU queue.

Comment: Collect a sample of your stuck process and edit your question to include it. If your whole computer is locked up then it seems like maybe a GPU panic/restart. In that case, it's a bug in the graphics driver or the like and you need to take it up with Apple.

Comment: Ken, unfortunantely StackOverflow is not allowing me to post the sample as it says it is not properly formatted code.